# How do you install .Net Core on Ubuntu without using sudo?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .net-core

The current installation instructions for Ubuntu 14 require the use of sudo (https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu). I don't have root permissions on a particular Ubuntu 12 server that I need to install .Net Core on. I have tried to download the Ubuntu files (https://www.microsoft.com/net/download#core) and install them manually but I get the following error when I run 'dotnet restore':

```
Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007001F
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running `dotnet` from the tar.gz works just fine for me on Ubuntu 14.

Running from the tar.gz or building from source does not work for me on Ubuntu 12. But Ubuntu 12 is not supported by `dotnet`, so I'm not surprised it does not work.

Not using `sudo` is not an issue, having old OS is.

Comment: I get a similar error message, just different error code, when I run dotnet on Ubuntu 15. I've accepted this as the answer since you are right to say that Ubuntu 12 isn't supported, even though there's no documentation that I have found that states this explicitly.

Comment: @AshleyS The page you linked to explicitly says it's for Ubuntu 14.04. Even Ubuntu 15 currently isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2971

it's a permissions issue and the fix:

> As soon as I do chmod +X to my binary (here it's tata) it works.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already tried that solution. It doesn't fix the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x you can use "The dotnet-install scripts are used to perform a non-admin install of the CLI toolchain". Although as mentioned results may vary depending on the linux os and version. I might recommend running a vm to test compatibilities with different versions if having issues. File permissions are also important.